# What exactly is the leader used for in DelayQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

I was trying to understand `DelayQueue` in `java.util.concurrent`, but `leader` confused me.

First of all, we can implement a DelayQueue without `leader` like this:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        q.offer(e);

        if (q.peek() == e) {
            available.signal();
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        for (;;) {
            E first = q.peek();
            if (first == null) {
                available.await();
            } else {
                long delay = first.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                if (delay <= 0) {
                    return q.poll();
                } else {
                    available.awaitNanos(delay);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Secondly, it seems does not *minimize unnecessary timed waiting*. According to the annotation:

> This variant of the Leader-Follower pattern (http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/POSA/POSA2/) serves to minimize unnecessary timed waiting

I take that as minimizing `awaitNanos` (using `await` instead of `awaitNanos`) but I really doubt that. If the new element isn't the head of the queue, then no thread will be signalled. (see `offer` method as below)

```
if (q.peek() == e) {
    leader = null;  // set leader to null
    available.signal();
}
```

So it only makes a difference when new elements is the head. But in this case, the `leader` will be set to `null`, and the signalled thread won't go this way(`take` method):

```
else if (leader != null)
    available.await();
```

The thread will always do `awaitNanos`.

So, can anybody explain that to me? Did I got the wrong idea somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comment of source code:

> It waits only for the next delay to elapse, but other threads await
>   indefinitely.

The leader is not used for `minimizing awaitNanos`, it is used for avoiding unnecessary wake up & sleep. If you let all threads `available.awaitNanos(delay)` in `take` method, they will be called up simultaneously but only one can really get element from the queue, the others will fall into sleeping again, which is unnecessary and resource-wasting.

With  Leader-Follower pattern, the leader `available.awaitNanos(delay)`, the non-leader threads  `available.await()`. So the leader will wake up first and retrieving an expried element, then signal another waiting thread if necessary. This is more efficient.

### Example

Suppose I have one element `E` in the queue, it will be expried after `T` nanoseconds, and there are two threads `Thread_1` and `Thread_2`.

**Without leader**(the implemetion you provide in the question)

- `Thread_1` calls `take` method, and finds E is available after T nanoseconds, so it calls `available.awaitNanos(T)`.
- `Thread_2` calls `take` method, and finds E is available after T nanoseconds, so it calls `available.awaitNanos(T)`.

After `T` nanoseconds, `Thread_1` wake up and take element `E`. `Thread_2` wake up and get nothing, so it has to sleep again. **The wake up and sleep again of `Thread_2` is unnecessary.**

**With leader**

- `Thread_1` calls `take` method, and finds E is available after T nanoseconds, so it becomes leader and calls `available.awaitNanos(T)`.
- `Thread_2` calls `take` method, and finds E is available after T nanoseconds, but `Thread_2` also notices there is already a leader, so `Thread_2` calls `available.await()`.

After `T` nanoseconds, `Thread_1` wake up and take element `E`. `Thread_2` will sleep until new elements are put in the queue.

Comment: Does avoiding unnecessary wake up & sleep means using `await` instead of `awaitNanos`? You can take a look at my code, the `awaitNanos`  seems to be called as much as it is in `DelayQueue`. Would you please show me a concrete example?

Comment: Oh my god, that's really helpful. I wrote a example that two thread waiting in the first place, and an element offered after then, so both thread were awaiting under that condition. I was blocked there for a long time, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Collin no problem. In non-leader threads, using `available.await()` is more efficient. The thread calls `available.awaitNanos(T)` might not sleep and just spin for timeout, wasting hardware resources.

Comment: This is really helpful @xingbin, thanks! One more question about awaitNanos, when one thread is awaitNanos, the others are awaiting, if there is a signal, does the thread who is awaitNanos have higher priority to get called up, or everybody have to compete again?

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer to McGar's last comment, but don't have reputation to do that.

So I don't think leader thread is guaranteed to be called up first. The trick here is when you offer a new earliest item, you manually set leader = null, and then the awakened thread would become the new leader, no matter if it used to be leader or not.